# UIImagePickerController in iPhone OS 3.0

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using iPhone OS 3.0 SDK.
My requirement is that I want to get the image from the photo albums library and display it on an image view.
I am using the `UIImagePickerController`  for that.

But the problem is the `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)imageeditingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo`  delegate method is deprecated in iPhone OS 3.0 ,

Is there any alternative for getting the Image from the UIImagePickerController.

All suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

use this delegate method of UIImagePickerController in your implementation file.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

and don't forget to modify your header file with these two protocols

```
@interface photoAppViewController : UIViewController < UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate >
```

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of 3.0 here would break your and my NDA with Apple. However I can suggest that you look at the relevant header files (`mdfind didFinishPickingImage | grep 3.0` will find what you need quickly).

Answer (score 0):

Some one posted me the answer as below.

In UIImagePickerController.h you can see that there ist a method you
can use:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
```

The documentation does not show this method it is only in the .h file.

but I am still not getting the above method in the .h file